Why does an app depend on different glibc versions?
I have a weird situation. My Qt made app depends on a lot of various glibc and glibc++ versions. On Windows I didn't need to think about such things at all. But now it appeared that a linux build of my app would depend on so many different versions. How could that happen at all? I know there're some ways to use different versions, but I don't want to download them all, I would prefer to lessen the amount of versions needed, or maybe download a part of that version variety listed down below, if it's possible. Or to do it automatically. But if I could use just one glibc version, for example, I would be able to use linuxdeployqt.
Here's how I've learnt that, I've tried to run my app from DistributionKit made by CQtDeployer running AppName.sh:
username@username:~/Downloads/DistributionKit$ ./AppName.sh
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.32' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libQt5Network.so.5)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libQt5Network.so.5)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libQt5Network.so.5)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.13' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libicui18n.so.74)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libicui18n.so.74)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libicuuc.so.74)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libicuuc.so.74)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libicuuc.so.74)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libicuuc.so.74)
/home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/bin/AppName: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/username/Downloads/DistributionKit/lib/libicuuc.so.74)

P.S. The distro where DistributionKit was made is Kubuntu 24.04, the distro where it was tested and this error occurred is Ubuntu 20.04

Doesn't the log message tell you exactly how it happened? (You're using libraries built against several different glibc versions). Use a better package manager, or use the package manager your Linux distro provided consistently -- this class of problem never happens if you use only packages from a single consistent distro release, because when a Linux distro builds a set of packages they do so against only one glibc version; it's when you download 3rd-party tools that your distro didn't approve you get into this kind of mess.

One place to start would be to take a binary you natively built without using CQtDeployer, and use ldd to ask where the libraries came from. Anything that didn't come from your distro, pitch in the trash and replace with a distro-packaged version.

(The more heavyweight way to prevent this class of problem is to use tools like Nix, which run builds in a sandbox so they can't possibly access anything except their declared, hash-addressed dependencies at build time; but that's not necessarily a beginner-friendly toolchain).

Anyhow -- right now we don't know which distro you're running, we don't know how you downloaded/installed dependencies, and otherwise we don't have enough information to be able to reproduce the problem ourselves or test proposed fixes. Start by trying to build a proper [mre] -- the shortest possible set of code and list of steps someone can follow exactly as given without changes to see the same problem.

(...to caveat my very first comment: mixing packages built for different OS releases, even if you're using your OS's installation tool, can get you into this situation too; but the answer remains to not do that).

Hello, guys, thank you very much for your answers, they make it all much clearer. Here's a moment - I actually need to not use some system libraries of my distro: the distro has itself some qt libraries, but they has inappropriate version, and I need to use those ones from qt installation dir. Can that possibly affect dependencies on glibc somehow, should I check all those libraries with ldd?

Yes, each C library was compiled against some copy of libc, and when it was built on a different distro, that can be a different libc than your other libraries. Don't do that: If you need library versions from Kubuntu 24.04, build your software only with Kubuntu 24.04, don't mix things built on different distros. (Or, as previously referenced, use a completely independent package manager: If you build something against Nix with nixpkgs-24.05, then you'll get qt libraries and libc and everything else only from nixpkgs-24.04, no matter if it's Ubuntu or Kubuntu or anything else outside).


My Qt made app depends on a lot of various glibc and glibc++ versions.

That is completely normal and explained here.
